# Objective studies of Stack Overflow user behaviour

Tags: discussion

In the past I have read various paragraphs and half-pages on blogs and the like referencing Stack Overflow as a good case example of "Game Theory" in action and how the "Reputation" system encourages this and encourages users to add to the community of the site by carrying out the required tasks, such as opening/closing questions, editing answers, etc.

I have been digging around the search engines but found nothing thus far that seems to be what I want (*[such as this](https://wiki.creativecommons.org/wiki/Case_Studies/StackOverflow.com)*). I *think* I can in principle get the raw data (although I can't find it, at present), however I feel that in a perfect world the raw data is not really what I need as I don't have the knowledge to interpret it ... So:

## Can you reference any objective studies of user behaviour (or the statistics thereof) of Stack Overflow?

### Example

One part (of the whole topic) I am particularly interested in is an interpretation of how many users with the required Reputation threshold actually act to help the site, such as how many people have the reputation to re-open questions, and how many of these people actually *do*?

And then from these statistics summarising feedback such as that people who reach a required reputation will take part in new community upkeep activities for X amount of time, such as 3 months, before their involvement in this specific action decreases (assuming as they get used to it).

While it *might* be easy for me to get the raw statistics, I feel I may not be best placed to draw (any) correct conclusions from them, so if you know how to grab these stats, please share, but primarily I am looking for finding already completed papers exploring the statistic exploration of Stack Overflow (*and Stack Exchange in general*) users' behaviour.

I think this sort of objective study would be fascinating and I'm sure there are some useful studies of this sort of feedback already, but I can't find them. If you know of such things please let me know!

Many thanks.

Comment: You're aware of [SEDE](https://data.stackexchange.com/) where you can put together queries for any questions you have if it's public data? Also - you may wish to look at the [statistics tag](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/statistics) for nuggets of information the CMs/Devs have provided regarding queues and drop offs etc...

Comment: @JonClements thanks for the link, I wasn't specifically aware of SEDE (I know of it by indirect reference only). thanks

Comment: Do any of the papers [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/134495/academic-papers-using-stack-exchange-data) have information you're looking for?

Comment: @Andy that looks exactly the sort of resource I'm asking for, thanks. I'll look through these to see if they are, but yes, this is the sort of thig I'm looking for, thanks. (Unfortuately this didn't seem to appear in my search engine requests)

Comment: "Game Theory"? Don't you mean "gamification"?

Comment: Related: *[Where is Stack Overflow's public data dump?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19579)* and *[Database schema documentation for the public data dump and SEDE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2677)*.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A [list of academic papers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/134495/academic-papers-using-stack-exchange-data) is available on Meta.SE.

This contains a large list of papers that utilize Stack Exchange data, dating back to 2009. It is pretty well maintained by authors of new papers too.